# How to use multiple render textures and cameras?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, textures, render, render-to-texture

I simply need to write text on 3D sphere. But I want to change it at runtime as I want. So, using a premade material is not an option.

I tried to make this with render texture it works pretty well but when it comes to multiple objects with multiple different text I noticed I need multiple render textures, cameras and layers so that the texts in front of the cameras do not interfere with each other. But unity gives only 32 layers. I don't know how many object will be generated and create layer. It doesn't seem like a good practice.

Is there another way like render texture or is there a way to use render texture for different texts?
[image]

Comment: To be clear, changing the texture on the material is not a valid solution to your problem?  If that is the case, can you specify the reason changing the texture is not an option? For single characters, you could easily use an atlas of characters like a font atlas and use offset.  You could also place a canvas on your object and add text using the Text or TMP Text components.

Comment: When I put the canvas on the object, the canvas becomes visible when the object moves. Here's what I'm doing here. I print the number as text on canvas and put it in front of a separate camera. That camera output becomes a render texture and that render texture is on the object as a material. And how many objects will be and which numbers and letters will be written on it depends on the user, so I need to create a general structure. Maybe I overcomplicated the situation, I'm not sure.

Comment: I dont quite understand this part of your statement: `the canvas becomes visible when the object moves`.  The canvas is not something that can be visible, images and text parented to the canvas are.  Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I was referring to attaching a UI Canvas to the sphere object, and setting the canvas to world space.  [World Space Canvas Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html).  That does not wrap it on the sphere though..

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I tried. What I mean by become visible is because of canvas does not wrap the sphere when sphere moves you can see the canvas floating over sphere.

Comment: What if you use the render texture setup, and then create the texture from the output of the render texture camera.  In this way you really only need that 1 render texture setup.  Another option is to use a [decal](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.0/manual/renderer-feature-decal.html).  Not sure what the performance, but it is likely better than multiple renderer texture/camera setups.

Comment: I tried two other techniques about text on an object, but they don't make the effect that I want. I tried decal and it looks like its gonna work for me. I couldn't get to chance to go deeper, check performance etc. But probably im gonna go with the decal technique. Thank for the advice.